# Collections.max() Improper Arguments

Tags: java, collections, max, comparator

I'm simply trying to find the max of a list of "Officers". The specs of the assignment I'm working on don't allow me to make the Officers comparable, so instead I'm using a Comparator to compare them.

However, the compiler is complaining about the types of my arguments. Can anyone see what's wrong? (Don't worry about the return... I haven't done that yet.)

Outside of the fragment below, officers is a List<Officer> which has been initialized.

```
Collections.max(officers, new Comparator<Officer>()
    {
        public int compare( Officer a, Officer b )
        {
           return -1; //will do after
        }
    }
);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I added the "homework" tag...

Comment: What is  the exact error message?

Comment: The method max(Collection<? extends AnyType>, Comparator<? super AnyType>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Officer>, new Comparator<Officer>(){})

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's just complaining about my Generic definitions. However, I can't find my error.

Comment: Is officers a generic list?  In other words is it a List<Officer> or just a List?  Do you have more than one class named Officer?

Comment: Why haven't you posted the actual error message?

Comment: It turns out I imported the wrong Collections package.

We were given a custom Collections package from our textbook to use (which I completely forgot about), so it was pulling the method signature from that one instead.

It's all good now. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles just fine. Here's an [ideone.com demo](http://ideone.com/YNXPg)

```
import java.util.*;

class Officer {
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Officer> officers = new ArrayList<Officer>();

        Collections.max(officers, new Comparator<Officer>()
                {
                    public int compare( Officer a, Officer b )
                    {
                       return -1; //will do after
                    }
                }
            );
    }
}
```

So, nothing wrong with the code you posted. Must be something else that's wrong.

Comment: check the comments for the original post... chit.  A wild goose chase.